# Alternative to psfrag that works with matplotlib / Python?

Tags: graphics, psfrag

Is there an alternative to the psfrag library that works with plots made outside of the MATLAB program? For example, in Python, even if you save a figure with the .eps extension, it is not compatible with psfrag; the replacements don't occur.

Comment: That line of working is a bit outdated. Now often people use [matplotlib2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz)